# Taylor expansion and the intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function at a point $\mathbf a =(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$. Then for $\mathbf x = (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ close to $\mathbf a$, Taylor's theorem tells us 
$$
f(x,y) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) + \frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(a,b)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a) + R_2(x,y),
$$
where $R_2(x,y) = o(|x,y|^2)$, and $H(a,b)$ is the Hessian matrix for $f$.

I recently came across a statement claiming 
$$
f(x,y) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) + \frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(\alpha, \beta)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a)
$$
for $x > a$ and $y > b$, and for some $\alpha \in [a,x]$, $\beta \in [b,y]$. In particular, they chose $\alpha, \beta$ to eliminate the third-order terms. While I am confident that there are *some* $\alpha, \beta$ that may achieve this, what allows us to choose $a \leq \alpha \leq x$ and $b  \leq \beta \leq y$?

It strikes me as being similar to the intermediate value theorem applied to the function $$ (s,t) \mapsto \frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(s,t)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a),$$
and it would certainly follow if we could show either
$$
\frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(a,b)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a) \leq \frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(a,b)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a) + R_3(x,y) \leq \frac 1 2 \left(\mathbf x - \mathbf a\right)^t H(x,y)(\mathbf x - \mathbf a),
$$
or the analogous statement with the inequalities reversed, but I couldn't find anything on the statement of Taylor's theorem that guarantees this. **Does Taylor's theorem imply the above inequality, or the reverse of the above inequality?**

Comment: These things are always proved by restricting $f$ to the segment $(a, b)+t(x,y)$ (for $t\in [0, 1]$). The function of a single variable $\phi(t):=f((a, b)+t(x,y))$ satisfies $$\phi(1)=\phi(0)+\phi'(0)+\frac12 \phi''(\theta), $$ for a $\theta \in [0, 1]$. Unpacking this, you get what you are asking for.

Comment: Okay, it helps reducing it to the single-variable case, but it basically leads to the same question: can we say $\phi''(0) \leq \phi''(0) + R_3(1) \leq \phi''(1)$ or the opposite?

Comment: Correction: $\frac 1 2 \phi''(0) \leq \frac 1 2 \phi''(0) + R_3(1) \leq \frac 1 2 \phi''(1)$; can't seem to edit my original comment.

Comment: You get $\phi(t)=\phi(0)+\phi'(0)t+ \frac12 \phi''(\theta t) t^2, $ for a $\theta \in (0,1)$. Set $t=1$.

Comment: I guess I'm not used to seeing Taylor's theorem expressed in that way; more commonly I've just seen $\phi(t) = \phi(0) + \phi'(0)t + \frac 1 2 \phi''(0)t^2 + R_3(t)$ for $R_3(t) = o(t^3)$. Is that simply an equivalent expression of Taylor's theorem?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know what it was called though.